# Laravel 5.2.29 $error handling and Request file

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2.29 in one of my project. I am using Laravel Request file to validate my user inputs. If validator fails, the error message should be shown under the input fields.

But the problem is, if the validator fails, it doesn't show any error message nor submit the form. here is blade file which takes 3 inputs, email/password and password confirmation

test.blade.php

```
<!-- email input-->
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">email</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="Name" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter email address" class="form-control input-md" required="">
        {!! $errors->first('email','<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
      </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">password</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="Name" name="password" type="password"  class="form-control input-md" required="">
        {!! $errors->first('password','<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
      </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">Confirm Password</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="Name" name="password_confirmation" type="password"  class="form-control input-md" required="">
      {!! $errors->first('password_confirmation','<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
  </div>
</div>


   <!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="" name="" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

testRequest.php

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email'     => 'required|email',
            'password'  => 'required|min:3|confirmed'
        ];
    }
```

testController.php (resource controller)

```
public function store(testRequest $request)
    {
        $test = User::create([
          'email'    => $request->email,
          'password' => bcrypt($request->password);
        ]);
        return redirect("/");
    }
```

routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web']],function(){
  Route::resource('test','testController');
});
```

When I hit the submit button, with a different password in the confirm password field, It does not give me any error. Doesn't submit the form too; it should at least say the the password confirmation did not match. I see nothing wrong with my code. Is it the problem with version 5.2.29? The exact same thing works fine with 5.2.22.

Comment: have you define "use App\Http\Requests\testRequest"  in your controller ? because i am using same version and its works

Comment: @Vipul yes ofcourse. because if u dont add that, u will get an error just before navigating to the test page - class not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug. From laravel 5.2.29 the web middleware will be applied to all the routes by default. So writing the following code should not work.

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web']],function(){
  Route::resource('test','testController');
});
```

simply write `Route::resource('test','testController');` you can check route service provider